# how to boot linux kernel from USB?

Tags: usb, u-boot

i've a vendor-supplied uboot flashed into the NAND flash of my embedded device. My Linux kernel uImage is stored in my USB thumbdrive. How may I configure the uBoot to load the Linux uImage on my USB via the Putty terminal?

Comment: A 30 second google search shows you get to command mode by typing control-c whilst the system is booting. A `help` command may tell you about a `usb` or `usbboot` command. Do you know the parameters that are normally used to boot your system, in particular where the kernel should be loaded?

Comment: yeah I did -help earlier and tried the usbboot but the command returned with an error indicating '** no boot device **. However my USB is plugged onto the board itself. Are there any other environment variables that I need to set accordingly?

Comment: `usb start` perhaps

Comment: @Icarus, thanks. but following this I set tried usbboot it's still the same error though. Previously the uboot parameters boot from my nand on my dev. board but i'd like to boot from my USB for memory reasons for development.

Comment: I understand completely, but I am sorry I don't think I can help, perhaps someone else can?